# Angular Js : undefined value in pop up

Tags: angularjs

I get a problem in AngularJS when getting data from JSON using service factory ($resource)

```
services.factory('GetCustomerByEmailFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(url + '/customerService/getCustomerByMail?email=:email', {}, {
        getByMail: { method: 'GET', params: {email: '@email'} }
    });
});
```

this service works well

but the controller part doesn't work

```
app.controller('CustomerCreationCtrl', ['$scope','PostCustomerFactory', '$location','Subscription','AddNotificationFactory','$routeParams','GetCustomerByEmailFactory',
    function ($scope, PostCustomerFactory, $location,Subscription,AddNotificationFactory,$routeParams,GetCustomerByEmailFactory) {
        $scope.customer ={}; 
        $scope.not ={}; 
        $scope.aftercustomer ={}; 


        $scope.createNewCustomer = function(){

              Number($scope.customer.PhoneNumber);
              $scope.customer.SubscriptionDate = "1990-02-23T00:00:00";
              $scope.customer.ManagerIdCustomer=1;

              PostCustomerFactory.create($scope.customer);



            var customer = GetCustomerByEmailFactory.getByMail({email:$scope.customer.Email}).$promise;

            customer.then(function (responce){
                $scope.aftercustomer = responce;

                window.alert($scope.aftercustomer.Id);
                $scope.not.CustomerId =  $scope.aftercustomer.Id;
                $scope.not.ManagerId = $routeParams.id;

              AddNotificationFactory.create($scope.not);


            });               
                  $location.path("/login");
          };


    }]);
```

the window.alert show me an undefined value so that it doesn't get the data

Comment: You don't need the custom `getByMail` action. The pre-defined `get` action will do the same thing, ie `return $resource(url + '/customerService/getCustomerByMail')`

Comment: Are there any errors in your console? Can you add `console.log(responce)` before the `alert` line and check what is logged? Chances are, it doesn't have an `Id` property

Comment: Wondering how is the url variable populated and pass it in the service ?

Comment: this is what the console shows : $promise
 
 Object { then=function(),  catch=function(),  finally=function()}
$resolved
 
 true
$delete
 
 function(params, success, error)
$get
 
 function(params, success, error)
$getByMail
 
 function(params, success, error)
$query
 
 function(params, success, error)
$remove
 
 function(params, success, error)
$save
 
 function(params, success, error)
__proto__
 
 Resource { $get=function(),  $save=function(),  $query=function(),  more...}

Comment: Is that a console log of customer or responce? Can you include the actual response from the server (Network tab in the dev tools)?